# Match any character except '

Tags: regex, vba, vba7, vba6

I want to match any character (case insensitive) except when preceded by a single quote followed by the text On Error Goto:

Match:

```
on error goto err_handler
if aap = 0 then on error goto Myerrorhandler
    on error goto errorhandler1
   on error goto errorhandler2
```

Do not match:

```
' on error goto errorhandler3
'   if aap =0 then on error goto errorhandler4
Any line not containing On Error Goto
```

I tried: `[^']*(On Error Goto)` but that didn't work.

It is to test if an Errorhandler is used in procedures

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
^[^'\n\r]*On Error Goto
```

Use `i` case insensitive mode and `m` multiline mode. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/2QlwEd/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^'\n\r]*                any character except: ''', '\n' (newline),
                           '\r' (carriage return) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  On Error Goto            'On Error Goto'
```

Comment: for vba case insensitive is a property to set on the regex object of .IgnoreCase = True

Answer (score 2):

Updated link to regex test cases: https://regex101.com/r/UYll0h/6

Since there can be no character when `'` isn't there, therefore you will need to use a look-ahead assertion.

Since there can also be other characters of the code (other than `'`) in the line before `on error goto` (like in the line `if aap = 0 then on error goto Myerrorhandler`), to handle those, you will also need to put a condition to check if any character other than `'` is present after the look-ahead. This will be done by `([^']+)?`.

`^(?!')([^']+)?on error goto`

The `(?)` is called a look-ahead. It checks if the characters inside it are present or not. Unlike `[]`, `(?)` will assert true even when there are no characters. So for example, `[a]` will check if the first character is 'a', but any expression after it will check from the second character. On the other hand, `(?=a)` will check if the first character is 'a', and any expression after it will check from the **first character**. In other words, the look-ahead doesn't move the regex engine to the next character if a match is not found.